# Convert or cast Datetime2 and varchar into datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a date stored as **datetime2(7)** and a time stored as **varchar(5)**.

e.g.

Date = **2016-11-30 00:00:00.000000** (datetime2)

Time = **09:00** (varchar)

Output should be **2016-11-30 09:00:00.000000** (datetime).

How do I convert or cast these as a datetime.  I have tried several ways but have been unsuccessful.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What ways have you tried that didn't work? Could you provide some sample data and the expected output for people to work with.

Comment: Can you post sample data, just as the one you have in your database table?

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out.    convert(datetime, convert(char(8),DATE, 112) + ' ' + convert(char(8),TIME, 108))

Comment: Thanks Shungo. I thought i had ticked it when i got it answered. I've ticked it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simple as this?

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2(7)='2016-11-30 00:00:00.000000'
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(5)='09:00';

SELECT CAST(CAST(@d AS DATETIME) + CAST(@t+':00' AS DATETIME) AS datetime2(7))
```

Your time needs just `:00` to it, than you can cast this to `DATETIME`. Two values of type `DATETIME`can be added.

The whole expression can be re-converted to `DATETIME2`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
DECLARE @MYDATE DATETIME2;
DECLARE @MYTIME VARCHAR(5);

SET @MYDATE = '2016-11-30';  -- this is equal to 2016-11-30 00:00:00.000000 
SET @MYTIME = '09:00';
-- for datetime2
SELECT CAST(CAST(LEFT(@MYDATE,10) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + @MYTIME + ':00.000000' AS DATETIME2) 
-- for datetime
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(LEFT(@MYDATE,10) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + @MYTIME + ':00') -- for datetime
```